# CSS is not loading on dynamically generated laravel views

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel-5

I don't know if this question has been answered, cos i could not out together the right search keywords.

I have my stylesheets and JavaScript embedded in my default layout view. I have a shop view that shows all the products, and when you click one of the product, it should redirect to /shop/{product-name}
[this is the page it loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvQQn.png)
[This is how it out to load the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0nVV.png)

The problem is that the styleSheet is not loading in full

My shop controller:

```
public function show($productName)
    {
        $product = Product::where('name', $productName)->firstOrFail();
        return view('product')->with('product',$product);
    }

the linked assets:


    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('}css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" />

    <!-- Slick -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/slick.css') }}" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/slick-theme.css') }}" />

    <!-- nouislider -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/nouislider.min.css') }}" />

    <!-- Font Awesome Icon -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/font-awesome.min.css') }}">

    <!-- Custom stlylesheet -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/style.css') }}" />



<!-- Scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/slick.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/nouislider.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/jquery.zoom.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>
```

My stylesheet doesn't seem to be loading appropriately. I wish i can attarch some pictures.

what am i doing wrong please?

Comment: you have incorrect syntax `{{ URL::asset('}css/bootstrap.min.css') }}` you have a closing curly brace before `css`. also your browser check what path is being printed as the hrefs for all those files, check if theyre correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bootstrap stylesheet has a typo. Remove the `}` from the very beginning.

```
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" />
```